# Change field's label color in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to change color of field's label in Sales Order Records.

But result is not color changed label text but a long string like <span style = ... .

Please tell me, if someone has a experience of this kind of problem.
Thanks.

```
define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/log"], function (serverWidget, log) {
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        try {
            var form = context.form;
            var field = form.getField("entity");
            field.label = '<span style="background-color: yellow">Customer</span>';
        } 
        catch (e) {
            log.error("Error:", e.message);
        }
    }
  
    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the script type? I see that the "N/ui/serverWidget" is available only in the SuiteLet and UserEvent script types. Second, the .getField() method accepts an object as an argument {id: 'entity'} , not 'entity'

Comment: script type is UserEventScript. stand coding is getField(id: 'entity') but getField('entity') is also working.

Comment: For one thing, better to stick to the documented behavior (so `{id: 'entity'}`, not `'entity'`), but that's up to you, of course. Also, since you said that it works, I assume your script is run, you are sure of this. If yes, i.e. the script is deployed, it's run, then I believe there is an error. What does the error log say? On the deployment page, IIRC, you can view log messages

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior as it is the label.
It will take the information from your string and don't interpret it.
Use inspect element and you will see that your string is inside the double quote.
Netsuite doesn't allow to change the color like that.
The only way is to use DOM manipulation which isn't encouraged by NetSuite.

Answer (score 0):

Only way which is considered hack is inject HTML code .

So either your user event creating a new field of type INLINE HTML which will take the id of the entity field and inject css inside for it

or

a client script doing that .

My 2 cents as a developer is say no if the request you get will solve no problem at all.